# installing .NET framework 4 and tradetigersetup.msi

Tags: wine

my ubuntu version is 14.04
i want to install a windows software from website http://www.sharekhan.com/tradetigerinstalation/TTSetup.aspx [tradetiger advance]. it requires .NET Framework 4

i installed wine and configured wine to windows 7
then i installed .NET Framework 4
then i installed tradetigersetup.msi
when i run the software system gives error "there is no windows program configured to open this type of file"
please help
thanks in advance

Comment: ...and how do you run it? You forgot to post the exact command, so please add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to get it to run from WINE: it has a [garbage rating](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=15014).

I would suggest installing Windows from a Virtual Machine and install it from there. That will work.

Comment: I would suggest you the same.

Comment: can u guide me installing Windows from a Virtual Machine and further how do i install my software from there

Answer (score -2):

Wine is compatible to install .msi files as well either in Ubuntu or Mac. You need to configure your wine setup initially which I presume you have already done.

Just type `wine start fileName.msi`. This will automatically install your desired file.

Here is the supporting link to [the Wine FAQ](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ).